# Data Structure needed to find probability of co-occurrence of two words in a sentence?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

I have a large data set with almost 1 TB.

The data is just text.

I am supposed to find co-occurrence of two words together within whole corpus.

I need to look entire corpus and find probability of the occurrence.

In other words, I need to find all sentences where these two words appear together.

But I need to repeat this multiple times.

How would you approach this problem so that it takes less time?

I only know some basic Python.

Clearly constructing a for loop for each file and each sentences and counting one by one would take forever.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: This is too broad. You should show the code you have so far and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is:

1. Scan the text, identifying the sentences and the words that are in them. Write a text file containing that information. For example, if the first sentence in your first document is "It was a dark and stormy night." You would have this in your file:

   `1, 1, It
   1, 1, was
   1, 1, a
   1, 1, dark
   1, 1, and
   1, 1, stormy`

When you're done, you have a *huge* text file that contains one line for every word in every document.

Then, you sort that file by word, document, and sentence number.

Now you can go through that file and create an index by word. Basically, that shows which sentences each word is in. For example, the entries for "dark" and "stormy" might look something like:

```
dark: 1:1, 3:8, 22:99, ...
stormy: 1:1, 12:6, 22:99, ...
```

Now if somebody asks you to tell them in which sentences "dark" and "stormy" occur, you can get the lists for the two words, do a set intersection, and return the result (1:1, 22:99 in this case).

This is not a particularly difficult thing to do for a small amount (a few megabytes) of data. It would be a challenging exercise for somebody with only a little bit of programming experience. Doable, but difficult.

When working with terabytes, though, you either have to be very creative with your data structures, or have the ability to throw a whole lot of hardware at the problem. It's definitely not a problem that I would expect a beginning programmer to tackle.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you very much.